# C code and making near zero negative values zero

Tags: c, zero

I am dealing with a mesh model having X Y Z points, such that I want to cut my model in half along the Y=0 plane.  Below is a sample of the data I am dealing with.  What happens has the mesh is exported from my CAD program even though I cut it using a Y=0 plane I will still get some Y values like -0.0000001234.

My model is inches, and I only need accuracy / correctness to 0.001 or 0.0001.  After that something like -0.000001 or more negative I just want to be 0.0 without a -

```
-18.801138     0.188375       39.370000
-19.209594     0.124526       39.370000
-19.650462     0.055230       39.370000
-19.245374     -0.000000      39.370000
-18.641099     -0.000000      39.370000
-18.212279     -0.000000      39.370000
-17.835492     -0.000000      39.370000
-17.505417     -0.000000      39.370000
-17.136364     -0.000000      39.370000
-16.704553     -0.000000      39.370000
-16.305413     -0.000000      39.370000
-15.932022     -0.000000      39.370000
-15.500000     -0.000024      39.370000
```

Having played with this data set, I still don't understand why that negative sign is persisting even when I read in this sample XYZ data set which is an ascii text file just as you see it there.

When I do

```
double y;

/* read that -0.000000 from the text file and store into  y  */

if ( y < 0 )
   y = 0;
```

why does the negative sign persist?  Does this kind of thing have a name for it, and what's the best way to deal with this?  I basically know up front that any Y value should not be negative so if it is I want it to be printed out as `0.000000` in my text file, and I haven't been able to make it happen.

This is in basic C, using gcc, in RHEL 7.9 x86-64.

update: just recognized `y = 0` and changed it to `y = 0.0` and that seemed to correct that `-0.000000`.  As to why this all technically happens if someone could explain would be cool.

Comment: You are working with float number, the perfect 0.0 doesn"t exist in memory, check how float numbers are stored, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format, it's probably because of that

Comment: I think `y = 0;` and `y = 0.0;` should compile to exactly the same machine code instructions

Comment: It does, there's an implicit cast happening there.

Comment: Use `(y <= 0)` as in [this ideone snippet](https://ideone.com/AMtPfR) and as @Blindy suggests in the answer.

Comment: @SidoShiro92: Every floating-point format is, by the definition in the C standard and other common definitions, capable of representing zero exactly.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I meant from a function computing, it's "hard" to get a perfect zero, but during initialization of course you can set to a perfect 0 flaot value

Answer (score 2):

Let's start by saying that for double precision numbers, 0 is signed. To quote the [IEEE 754 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754):

> Moreover, there are two zero values, called signed zeros: the sign bit specifies whether a zero is +0 (positive zero) or −0 (negative zero).

As to why the value persists after your test, you're checking if the value is less than 0. -0 is not less than 0, it's equal to 0, so your `y = 0;` line never executes.